# Cant display data after using .getDocuments in Firestore and trying to place the document IDs into an array and displaying them using a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class

```
class List {

var name: String

init(name: String) {

    self.name = name

}
}
```

which is used to make the array. I declared the array

```
var providersList = [List]()
```

then used the function

```
func downloadData() {

    db.collection("\(finalSelection.lowercased())_providers").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
         if let err = err {
             print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
         } else {
             for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                self.providersList.append(List(name: "\(document.documentID)"))


             }
         }
     }

 }
```

to download the data. The data downloads correctly because there is no error and I also used `print()` to confirm the data is correct. However, when I use the functions for tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MoreCell", for: indexPath) as! MoreInfoTableViewCell

    cell.moreInfoLabel.text = providersList[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return providersList.count
}
```

the table view isn't populated. I know this method works because I have used something similar to it in another area of my code (not downloading the data but populating the table view)

Edit: I tried to remove the class and append to the array normally without using the `.name` from the class. However, this didn't do anything either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found out the solution to this when I was laying in bed about to sleep (lol). In the function `downloadData()`, I have to put self.tableView.reloadData() after appending to the array. I will include this for anyone who faced a similar problem like me.

func downloadData() {

```
db.collection("\(finalSelection.lowercased())_providers").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
     if let err = err {
         print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
     } else {
         for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            self.providersList.append(List(name: "\(document.documentID)"))
            self.tableView.reloadData()


         }
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Pretty good solution but you will want to move the self.tableView.reloadData() immediately *after* the for loop but still within the else, otherwise it will be called repeatedly and refresh the ui causing flicker. Populate first, then refresh.